# $u^2$+$(u-2v-1)^2$=$-4v(u+v)$, then u+3v

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My attempt:
$2u^2+4v^2-4uv+4v-2u+1=-4uv-4v^2$,

Then, 
$8v^2+4v+2u^2-2u=-1$

Not able to go further than this. Is there a way to reach to the factorisation of this?

Comment: What is the question supposed to be asking? Do you want to factor the expression? What does $u+3v$ have to do with anything?

Comment: @Cardioid_Ass_22: If $u^2$+$(u-2v-1)^2$=$-4v(u+v)$, then what is the value of $u+3v$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move everything to the left and complete the square:
$$\color{red}{u^2+4v(u+v)}+(u-2v-1)^2=0 \Rightarrow \\
\color{red}{(u+2v)^2}+(u-2v-1)^2=0 \Rightarrow \\
\begin{cases} u+2v=0\\ u-2v-1=0 \end{cases} \Rightarrow (u,v)=(0.5, -0.25).$$
Hence:
$$u+3v=0.5+3(-0.25)=-0.25.$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$8\left(v+\dfrac14\right)^2+2\left(u-\dfrac12\right)^2=0$$

Alternatively

$$-8+4+4=(4u-2)^2+(8v+2)^2$$

For real $a,a^2\ge0$

Comment: bhattachrjee, could you explain a bit please?

Comment: @Sherlock, We have sum of two square $=0$ right? What can you infer using my last Hint